# Spring Dependency Injection via @Configuration, @Bean and @Component

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-webflux

I have been struggling to understand fully how the dependency injection works via `@Configuration`, `@Bean` and `@Component` annotations.

My Code is as follows.

1) `Route.kt`

```
/* Route.kt */

package com.example.service

import com.example.service.ports.AutoComplete
import com.example.service.ports.Validation
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import org.springframework.http.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.router

@Configuration
@Suppress("unused")
class Routes(private val autoComplete: AutoComplete,
             private val validation: Validation) {

    @Bean
    fun route() = router {
        ("/service-lookup" and accept(APPLICATION_JSON)).nest {
            GET("/auto-complete/{service}", autoComplete::autoComplete)
            GET("/validation/{service}", validation::validation)
        }
    }
}
```

2) `ServiceImpl.kt`

```
package com.example.service

import com.example.service.ports.AutoComplete
import com.example.service.ports.Validation
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.ServerRequest
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.ServerResponse
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono

@Component
@Suppress("unused")
class ServiceImpl: AutoComplete, Validation {
    override fun autoComplete(request: ServerRequest): Mono<ServerResponse> {
        TODO("not implemented autoComplete") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

    override fun validation(request: ServerRequest): Mono<ServerResponse> {
        TODO("not implemented validation") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
}
```

3) `ports/AutoComplete.kt`

```
package com.example.service.ports

import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.ServerRequest
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.ServerResponse
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono

interface AutoComplete {

    fun autoComplete(request: ServerRequest): Mono<ServerResponse>

}
```

4) `ports/Validation.kt`

```
package com.example.service.ports

import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.ServerRequest
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.ServerResponse
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono

interface Validation {

    fun validation(request: ServerRequest): Mono<ServerResponse>

}
```

My question is, how does the `route` bean created from `Route.kt` know that the `autoComplete` and `validation` should use the `ServiceImpl` class from `ServiceImpl.kt`?

Answer (score 1):

The following description of the Spring mechanism is simplified for you example:

At startup Spring Boot scans the classpath for all classes annotated with `@Configuration`, `@Component`, etc and builds a bean definition list. In your example it finds the `Routes` and `ServiceImpl` classes.

After this Spring scans all methods of every class in the bean definition list for further `@Bean` annotations and adds the method (especially the return type) to the bean definition list. In your example it finds the `route` method.

After the first scan Spring knows which bean types are present and which bean class implements which interfaces. And Spring knows which constructor parameters,  `Inject` targets or method parameters are required to create an instance of the bean. With this information Spring instantiates the beans in the correct order.
In your example Spring knows that `Router` requires `AutoComplete` and `Validation` and that `ServiceImpl` implements these interfaces. Therefore it has to instantiate `ServiceImpl` first and `Router` later.

If more then one bean implements the same interface Spring throws an exception and you have to further qualify the bean.

Comment: i still don't 100% understand but you helped me a lot just now. so, I get it now that Spring knows the dependency and so, it instantiates `ServiceImpl` first and `Router` later. But, how does `route` method knows to call `autoComplete` method of `ServiceImpl`?

Comment: `ServiceImpl` implements the `AutoComplete` interface and overrides the `autoComplete` method. The `Router` class requires a bean that implements `AutoComplete` in the constructor and Spring provides the `ServiceImpl` bean. In the `route` function you access with `autoComplete::autoComplete` exactly the method of the `ServiceImpl` instance.

Answer (score 1):

I will try to clarify:

**@Component** - It is tighty bound to the spring auto configuration and component scanning. Everything marked with Component will be picked up as long as you have it in the path of the component scanning defined by @ComponentScanned annotation.  The @Components  come into three flavours:

A) Repositories - used for persistence

B) Controllers for example RestController

C) Service - a service without state . F.ex a Facade.

This annotation is used to automate the construction of the Application context,as well as to define a stereotype for the bean bound to the context.

**@Bean** - @Bean and @Component have the same goal, but @Bean is not a @Component. They both build the application context, but they do it in a very different way. While @Component defines a stereotype of the class and tells spring to pick it up. The Bean has full responsibility of manually configuring the instance of what you are creating. The implementation and the configuration are fully separated and you receive a higher degree of control on how exactly the Bean is generated.

**@Configuration** is used in conjunction with @Bean. @Bean in contrast to @Component is a method level annotation therefore the usual case is that a class is marked with @Configuration and then one ro more methods annotated with @Bean are following.

**In your particular example**
You have create a @Bean router. The router was created based on the autoComplete and validation which were injected in the Routes. Spring was able to figure out what to inject based on the best matching candidate. Since you have a single implementing bean instance of the two interfaces AutoComplete, Validation it injects it. In your case autoComplete and validation will point to the same instance.

Comment: what do you refer to by "single implementing bean instance of the two interfaces"? is that the `ServiceImpl`?

Comment: @thecruisy Yes, potentialy you could have had multiple implementations of these interfaces in which case it would not have been deterministic operation to decide on which implementation should be injected. In such cases one option would be to use a "@Qualifier" to determine on the correct implementation.

Comment: is there a way to specify which implementation to use in any config files instead of using the `@Qualifier` annotation (in the case of having multiple implementations)? also, on the `@Component` explanation above, especially this part "as well as to define a stereotype for the bean bound to the context", do you mean that any class that is annotated by `@Component` is considered by Spring as a candidate for a `bean` implementation?

Comment: @thecruisy any class defined with "@Component" or any annotation subclassing from "@Component" will be bound to the application context as long as it is in the scanned path. You can use xml if you prefer over annotations. Also you can mark with "@Primary" if you have one implementation that is used as a default implementation.

Comment: right. i think i sort of understand it more now (though still not fully). i guess i need to do more project on this and read up on definitions. thanks for your answers! one question on the testing side, since the `Routes` class actually expects 2 x arguments `autoComplete` and `validation`, when I try to use `WebTestClient.bindToRouterFunction(Routes().route()).build`, it obviously complains that no values of `autoComplete` and `validation` are passed. any advice? or should this be on a separate question?